# resonance demodulation for bearing faults

Tags: frequency, demodulation

Can someone explain me how are the different frequency bands useful for detecting bearing faults using resonance demodulation?

Answer (score 1):

This [presentation](http://www.sem.org/PDF/Bearings_and_gearbox_diagnostics.pdf) has a pretty good overview of characterizing bearing faults. In essence, once the measured frequency content does not match what is considered a good response from a bearing, it can be flagged as faulty or nearing fault.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this presentation. But it still doesn't answer my doubt. I need to know how to select the frequency bands in resonance demodulation.